# asp.net - How to use variable in Sql?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a problem. 
How to use variable in SQL question? 
This code doesn't work:

```
   cmd.CommandText = "select Id, Name from tblFiles WHERE email = 'CurrentUser'";
   cmd.CommandText = "select Id, Name from tblFiles WHERE email = '+CurrentUser'";
   cmd.CommandText = "select Id, Name from tblFiles WHERE email = '$CurrentUser'";
   cmd.CommandText = "select Id, Name from tblFiles WHERE email =' +CurrentUser'";
   cmd.CommandText = "select Id, Name from tblFiles WHERE email = CurrentUser";
```

I must download from database date where email is CurrentUser = User.Identity.Name.

```
 private void BindGrid()
    {
        string CurrentUser = User.Identity.Name;
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {

            if (CurrentUser != null)
            {
             using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
             {
                GridView GridView1 = LoginView3.FindControl("GridView1") as GridView;
                cmd.CommandText = "select Id, Name from tblFiles WHERE email = 'CurrentUser'";
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                GridView1.DataBind();
                con.Close();
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Try this piece of code
`cmd.CommandText = string.Format("select Id, Name from tblFiles WHERE email = '{0}'", CurrentUser);`

Comment: @KarthickNS NO NO NO NO NO!!!! That is very very very bad.

Comment: Yes Marc Gravell, using parameters is the best way

Comment: @KarthickNS the *only* way that doesn't get your site hacked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you want you should use parameters. You can read more about them [here].(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
private void BindGrid()
{
    var CurrentUser = User.Identity.Name;
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {

        if (CurrentUser != null)
        {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                GridView GridView1 = LoginView3.FindControl("GridView1") as GridView;
                cmd.CommandText = "select Id, Name from tblFiles WHERE email = @CurrentUser";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@CurrentUser", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                cmd.Parameters["@CurrentUser"].Value = User.Identity.Name;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                GridView1.DataBind();
                con.Close();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to make use of [Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
    cmd.CommandText = "select Id, Name from tblFiles WHERE email = @CurrentUser";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CurrentUser", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    cmd.Parameters["@CurrentUser"].Value = User.Identity.Name;
```

Answer (score 1):

As is noted: parameters are the way to go here. But it doesn't need to be hard - you can use tools like "dapper" to make it painless:

```
string email = User.Identity.Name;
var row = con.Query("select Id, Name from tblFiles WHERE email = @email",
    new { email }).SingleOrDefault();
if(row != null) {
    int id = row.Id;
    string name = row.Name;
    // ...
}
```

(here `Query` creates an `IEnumerable<dynamic>` based on the columns, and `SingleOrDefault` selects exactly 0 or 1 rows). All the other methods you would want (`ExecuteReader`, `ExecuteScalar`, multi-grid handling, etc) are all there too.

You can also use `Query<User>` to populate a `User` by matching columns to fields/properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd.CommandText = "select Id, Name from tblFiles WHERE email = @CurrentUser";    
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentUser", User.Identity.Name);
```

This should add parameters to your command.